# 1st two arguments of Excel LOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple rows of data: Row 3 is a date header, incrementing 1 month per column. Row 4 has multiple columns with values between `0` & `>0`. The formula below, written by someone else, finds the last column with data `>0`, and returns the corresponding month:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($D4:$AH4)>0),$D$3:$AH$3)
```

I do not understand what action is performed by the `2` value, and I further do not understand what `1/(($D4:$AH4)>0` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a shortened example:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($D4:$G4)>0),$D$3:$G$3)
```

(($D4:$G4)>0) is going to return an array of true and falses. For example:

```
={TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
```

When dividing by 1/{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE), you will get:

```
={1,1,#DIV/0!,1}
```

Besides an error, the only number that is going to be returned is a 1.  So because 2 (The first parameter in the lookup) is larger than all the numbers in the array, when you search the array it's going to find the last position in the array with a 1. In my example this will be the 4th(Last) position which will then be used to return the 4th position in the last array, "Tiger":

```
=LOOKUP(2,{1,1,#DIV/0!,1},{"Cat","Dog","Bird","Tiger"})
```

Instead of a 2, you very well could use a 3 or a 4,etc. and you would get the same result; however, it's a best practice to use a 2 here.

To get a good idea of what's happening you can always use evaulate formula found on the "Formulas" tab; however, I prefer to just highlight sections of the code and press the F9 key to see how it calculates

Comment: more info on LOOKUP https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/99621-lookup-value-unsorted-data.html) post to mrexcel, the $D4:$AH4>0 will first produce a ton of 1s and 0s when it is true or false. Putting that under 1 will produce a ton of 1 and div/0 errors. Looking for two will produce the last instance of "1" (the last row with data) because 2 is bigger than everything else.